# Why deleting one dimension in tensor causes InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

Part of my codes:

```
reshape_out = Reshape((3, 21, 1), input_shape=(21*3,), name='reshape_to_3_21')(output3d)
drop_out = Lambda(lambda x:x[0:2, :, :], output_shape=(2, 21, 1), name='projection')(reshape_out)
flatten_out = Flatten()(drop_out)
```

I got the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [2,63], In[1]: [42,1024].
```

But if

```
drop_out = Lambda(lambda x:x[0:2, :, :], output_shape=(2, 21, 1), name='projection')(reshape_out)
```

is removed, everything is OK. Why?

Comment: Could you post the entire stack trace? It seems as though the reshape is not working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First axis is the batch axis and it seems you are mistakenly slicing it instead of the second axis:

```
def drop_output_shape(shp):
    return (shp[0], 2) + shp[2:]

drop_out = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0:2, :, :], 
                  output_shape=drop_output_shape, name='projection')(reshape_out)
```

Comment: please can you help in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225332/matrix-size-incompatible